# SEVERE: listenerStart and memory leak ERROR

Tags: jsf, liferay, tomcat7

I use apache myfaces 2.1.6 and tomcat 7. When I deploy my portlet I get listenerStart error.

```
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
22 2013 10:20:57 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/myPortlet] startup failed due to previous errors
10:20:57,590 INFO  [PluginPackageUtil:1099] Reading plugin package for rigensis-web-cust-application-regular-payment
10:20:57,592 WARN  [PluginPackageUtil:1058] Plugin package on context rigensis-web-cust-application-regular-payment cannot be tracked because this WAR does not contain a liferay-plugin-package.xml file
10:20:57,595 INFO  [PortletHotDeployListener:549] Unregistering portlets for myPortlet
10:20:57,603 INFO  [PortletHotDeployListener:580] 1 portlet for myPortlet was unregistered
22 2013 10:20:57 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/myPortlet] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@5f734d]) and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class org.apache.camel.core.xml.CamelProxyFactoryDefinition=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@8ad0bb, class org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@18db6b4, class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@d6081f, class java.util.ArrayList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@1af402a}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22 2013 10:20:57 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/myPortlet] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1@9dc4d6]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e5d582]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: deleting temp work folders and removing this portlet from webapps and then deploying portlet should work

Answer (score 0):

You mean `...because this WAR does not contain a liferay-plugin-package.xml file...`

If this is a plugin that should be managed by Liferay, you should just provide the file if it bothers you. Also, you can help Liferay's deployer to determine the kind of plugin you're deploying by having its name end in `-portlet` - e.g. instead of calling it `myPortlet`, call it `my-portlet`

If this isn't your problem: You only quote the log and ask for help - but don't give any clue on what the actual question is